# page.getElementsByClassName with phantom js node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to open a URL and click a button with [phatom-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/simple.js) but I'm unable to use getElementsByClassName with it.

This is the message I'm receiving.

```
(node:10960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: _page.getElementsByClassName is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
phantom.create([])
        .then( instance => {
            console.log('CREATEPAGE');
            return instance.createPage();
        })
        .then( page => {
             console.log('PAGE');
            _page = page;
            return page.open(`url_here`);         
        })
        .then( status => {
            console.log('STATUS');
            console.log(status);
            return _page.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send send-container");
        })
        .then(function(input){
            console.log('CLICK');
            return input[0].click();

        });
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you know which promise is being rejected?

Comment: this 
return _page.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send send-container");

Comment: Well the error tells you what is wrong `_page` doesn't have a method called `getElementsByClassName` verify the api calls you are making are valid

Comment: well, `_page` probably doesn't have that method, it's a `document` method, so it may be (I don't know phantom well) `_page.document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @JaromandaX with document it gives this error: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of undefined

Comment: oh, so the original code doesn't complain about `getElementsByClassName` not being a function? if you `console.log(typeof _page.getElementsByClassName)` does it output `function`? ... and `CLICK` is never logged to the console?

Comment: @JaromandaX it returns undefined

Comment: having read the [github page you linked to](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) it seems you would need to do something like `return _page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send send-container"));`